# IFTTT: "Your service must have at least one query." Why?

Tags: service, triggers, action, ifttt

I'm creating my own service and in the service checklist this error is shown:

***Your service must have at least one query.***

My question is: is it really necessary? I mean, If I don't create a query, my service will never by published ( i.e. will it be rejected during the Publish step)?

The fact is that my service needs only trigger and action (an no any query).

Please help.

[Error message from IFTTT service editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsEsX.png)

Answer (score 0):

For publishing the service it needs atleast one query. sample code for the query can be found from the example service "Hello world" from ifttt documentation (https://platform.ifttt.com/docs/example_services)